# How to convert varchar with short time zone to timestamp in oracle

Tags: oracle

We have date stored in varchar2 column as 'Tue Dec 18 16:49:31 EST 2018', I would like to convert this to timestamp. Tried with `to_timestamp('Tue Dec 18 16:49:31 EST 2018','DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TS YYYY')` but not working. Please help.

Comment: What is `EST`? Check with `SELECT TZNAME, TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE TZABBREV = 'EST'`

Comment: EST is Eastern Standard Time, and it is available in V$TIMEZONE_NAMES. The data is coming from different system and we don't have control on the format also.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to preserve the time zone information, you have to use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`, otherwise you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
           'Tue Dec 18 16:49:31 EST 2018', 
           '\w+ (\w+) (\d+) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) (\w+) (\d+)', 
           '\5-\1-\2 \3 \4'
        ), 
        'YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR',
        'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
           'Tue Dec 18 16:49:31 EST 2018', 
           '\w+ (\w+) (\d+) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \w+ (\d+)', 
           '\4-\1-\2 \3'
        ), 
        'YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS',
        'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')
FROM DUAL;
```

However, it will fail for `EDT`, see:

```
SELECT TZNAME, TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME) 
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES 
WHERE TZNAME IN ('EST','EDT')
```

You could use `REPLACE('Tue Dec 18 16:49:31 EDT 2018', 'EDT', 'EST5EDT')` to make it working.